# Save text and show him in another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to write text in one page and save him so it show in another page . I give an example: my javascript generate randomly quote and i want save that quote ,so that quote appear in certain page like myfavoritequotes.html

Comment: Show us what you have so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localstorage. Otherwise you have to load the next page asynchronously.

```
localStorage.setItem('yourKey', yourData);
```

then on the next page

```
localStorage.getItem('yourKey');
```

Comment: can you explain it better im not very good in javascript

Comment: Sorry, the explanation here it sums it up fairly well. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @user3316437 - First go to this page and type something in: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jaJGu/ , then go here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/fZ5S9/

Comment: @MildFuzz - Probably the JavaScript part.  ¯\( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)/¯